# Setting up logging to store *complete* logs for function runs

Tags: azure-functions

I'm having a problem finding sufficient documentation to set up diagnostic logging within Azure functions to store *complete* logs of function runs.

At present I can only see a complete log if I happen to be watching a function with the streaming log service at the time.

Logs are truncated when stored in tables and accessed either directly or via the UI, and I've tried setting blob storage for diagnostic logging in the UI, and even set to Verbose, all I get is a CSV file with a few lines of the functions runtime logging.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Insights to collect logs from your Function App, see

- [Azure Functions now has direct integration with Application Insights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/)
- [App Insights](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights)
- [Azure Functions Logging to Application Insights](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/06/20/azure-functions-logging-to-application-insights/)

Comment: That's all very well and good, but doesn't actually answer the question. In order to use App Insights (which I already have turned on) I will have to go through all my functions and rewrite them to use ILogger rather than Tracewriter. Apparently, in theory, I should be able to get full log traces that I currently produce, written to Blob storage where I can retrieve them. That's what I want.

Comment: @NichOverend Log entries writen to TraceWriter make it into App Insights without you needing to do anything special (other than turn it on). Check the traces table. If this is not working for you please let me know as I'd like to investigate.

Comment: @PaulBatum I'm not seeing anywhere near as much detail in AppInsights as I get in the standard invocation details log. I managed to find more detail by turning filtering off (or more on - the language is confusing - it's labelled filter, but acts additively, not subtractively), but even then, some of the detail is definitely missing. Also, is there an API for AppInsights, as I want to gather data from various places altogether on one page for debugging and support purposes when we run a beta phase. How can I assist you in looking further at this?

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example? Maybe post a github gist with a comparison?